# issue when retrieving elements from array of objects- objective C

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a class Person with variables name,age,local and about, i added  values of person object to a mutable array as shown:

```
Person *myPerson=[[Person alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *personArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

myPerson.name=namefield;    //'namefield' retrieved from db
myPerson.age=agefield;      //'agefield' retrieved from db
myPerson.local=locfield;    //'locfield' retrieved from db
myPerson.about=aboutfield;  //'aboutfield' retrieved from db

[personArray addObject:myPerson];
```

and I have problem when trying to print out the elements using below code;which shows last element repeatedly,

```
for (int i = 0; i < [personArray count]; i++){
    Person * p = [personArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"name %@",p.name);
    NSLog(@"age %@",p.age);      
}
```

hope you will be kind to me as I am a new guy to iPhone development. Thanks.

Comment: what is the error or issue ??

Comment: last element of  personArray shows repeatedly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add new object instance in a mutable array using same object reference as the previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359023/), [Array addobject is changing all array values instead of just appending](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8714385)

Comment: Are you using any loop to insert multiple objects into array? If yes then how have you implemented that loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array addObject is changing all array values instead of just appending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714385/array-addobject-is-changing-all-array-values-instead-of-just-appending)

Comment: Are you using MRC or ARC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Person *myPerson=[[Person alloc]init];` this line, it seems you have written this line outside the `for` loop where you are adding objects. As such there is only one instance of `person class` being there represented by all objects of the array. put that line inside the `for` loop, so that at every iteration a new `person` object is added to the array.

Answer (score 3):

you can write code like this

```
NSMutableArray *personArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=o;i<noOfRecords;i++)
{
    Person *myPerson=[[Person alloc]init];
    myPerson.name=namefield;    //'namefield' retrieved from db
    myPerson.age=agefield;      //'agefield' retrieved from db
    myPerson.local=locfield;    //'locfield' retrieved from db
    myPerson.about=aboutfield;  //'aboutfield' retrieved from db

    [personArray addObject:myPerson];
    [myPerson release];
}
```

Then retrieve array this may be helpful because you are fetching only last row

release if ARC is not enabled otherwise no need to release

Comment: yes that is my point but i come to know later that you also post same

Comment: yeah sure ..no issue, things should be clear to him, and that is all that matters :) :) and you provide a nice code showing him cheers

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are re-using `myPerson`.  When you add an object to an array, it does not create a copy of it.  Instead, it just stores a reference to the object, therefore when you change it later it changes ALL of the references pointing to it.

Change this line:

```
[personArray addObject:myPerson];
```

To this line:

```
[[personArray addObject:myPerson] copy];
```

in order to add a **copy** of your person to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person *myPerson=[[Person alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *personArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

myPerson.name=namefield;    //'namefield' retrieved from db
myPerson.age=agefield;      //'agefield' retrieved from db
myPerson.local=locfield;    //'locfield' retrieved from db
myPerson.about=aboutfield;  //'aboutfield' retrieved from db

for (int i = 0; i < [personArray count]; i++) 
{
    [personArray addObject:myPerson];
    NSLog(@"name %@",p.name);
}
```

Try this...